# Performance improvement when reading txt file

Tags: python, performance, processing-efficiency

I am looking for a performance improvement on a taks that I am doing.

The task is quite simple: from .txt file to a SQL database.

So the txt file consists in a bunch of lines looking like this one:

`200101   35.922    2.127    1.182    1.182    1.418    1.654`

Explanation:

`200111`: is info, consists in `20` **(channel num)** `01` **(page num)** `11` **(code)**

the rest of the double values are just values: I1, I2...up to I6

Thus, the SQL file will have as a columns `[channel, page, code, I1, I2, I3, I4, I5, I6, passed]`

The problem is that, on the txt file,  `code` can be 00, 11, 10, 01, or 22 and, depending on the code, I need to perform one action or another with the values of I to decide passed=1 or passed=0. For example, in this case, if `code=11`, `passed=1 if I1>I3 and I6<1`

The lines on the txt are sorted by code.

So, with that explanation, what I am basically doing is something like that:

```
with open(txtFile, 'r') as txt: 
    for line in txt:
        currentLine = line.split(' ')[0]
        if currentLine.endswith('00'):
            #do some actions here
        if currentLine.endswith('01'):
            #do some actions here
        #...
        #and so on
        # and of course write to SQL file
```

So, is it anything better or more time-efficinet than checking each line with an `if`clause

Comment: Why don't you profile your script and find where it's slow at instead of just guessing? The time taken by a few `if` statements is going to be dwarfed by disk IO.

Comment: I would use the csv module to parse your file

Comment: @Colonel, that is done, the bottle neck is located on that part of the code

Comment: In the `if` statement checking? Sounds fishy. You could store functions in a dictionary and use the two first characters as the keys.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, you mean read txt file with csv module or...?

Comment: Yes, what are you doing with the rest of the row values?

Comment: How are you writing to the database?  For example, are you using placeholders, do you do some complex SQL condition?  Which database module are you using?

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo, that sounds like a good suggestion, and @PadraicCunningham im not doing much more than what is said in the post...just some simple operations with the `I` values to decide `passed` 1 or 0

Comment: @cdarke im just directly writing each value to the database, channel, page, code...etc using the usual """INSERT INTO myTable VALUES(channel, page....)....etc"""

Comment: I got downvote?, is it that bad question??

Comment: did you try using `elif` statement instead of `if if if if if` ?

Comment: @FunkySayu no I didn't, but to be honest I do not think there is a  big difference

Comment: Not really, but for a 2 billions line file, it could. What did you use for profiling ?

Comment: You might find pandas useful

Comment: @PadraicCunningham.....im reading about pandas....sounds like that could do it in a more efficinet way, thanks

Comment: I'm not sure how it works in the background, but I would use a temp variable like `code = currentLine[-2:]` and I would check this variable like `if code == '00': `. I would also use `elif`s to avoid unnecessary checks. It seems to me that those are small improvements that could get your work done faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might get some very slight improvement only doing a split once:

```
currentLine = line.split(' ', 1)[0]
```

Or if the first field you're interested in always has the same length (6 using your example), you could try to fetch only those characters:

```
currentLine = line[:6]
```

If the length of the first field is variable you could try this:

```
currentLine = line[:line.index(' ')]
```

Here's some timings to see which is faster...

Your current method:

```
# python3 -m timeit -s "l = '200101   35.922    2.127    1.182    1.182    1.418    1.654'" "lineCode = l.split(' ')[0]"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.61 usec per loop
```

First suggestion (limit split to one occurrence):

```
# python3 -m timeit -s "l = '200101   35.922    2.127    1.182    1.182    1.418    1.654'" "lineCode = l.split(' ', 1)[0]"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.237 usec per loop
```

Second suggestion (use slice to get fixed length field):

```
# python3 -m timeit -s "l = '200101   35.922    2.127    1.182    1.182    1.418    1.654'" "currentLine = l[:6]"                                                                                             
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0708 usec per loop
```

Third suggestion (use slice + index to get variable length field):

```
# python3 -m timeit -s "l = '200101   35.922    2.127    1.182    1.182    1.418    1.654'" "currentLine = l[:l.index(' ')]"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.208 usec per loop
```

In my elementary testing, it seems suggestion 2 is the fastest if you can manage it. The other two suggestions are very similar in performance but better than your current method by a decent margin.

Obviously these timings will vary depending on the platform you're running them on but relatively speaking the performance improvements should hold up anywhere.

Now, all that said, I agree with your other commentators that your slowness is probably coming from somewhere else. If I had to guess it would be your SQL INSERTs. The only thing I can suggest doing there is either a multiple INSERT if the database and driver allow it or writing your SQL statments to a properly formatted file and letting another tool do a bulk import (could even be called using Python subprocess module).

---

### Additional Thoughts

If you only need to test those two characters (the 5th and 6th) then this is the most efficient I found. It eliminates the inefficient `split` you're using and the slower `endswith`.

Yours:

```
# python3 -m timeit -s "l = '200101   35.922    2.127    1.182    1.182    1.418    1.654'" "currentLine = l.split(' ')[0]; currentLine.endswith('00')"                                                       
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.72 usec per loop
```

Better:

```
# python3 -m timeit -s "l = '200101   35.922    2.127    1.182    1.182    1.418    1.654'" "currentLine = l[:6]; lineCode = currentLine[4:]; lineCode == '00'"
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.161 usec per loop
```

Best:

```
# python3 -m timeit -s "l = '200101   35.922    2.127    1.182    1.182    1.418    1.654'" "currentLine = l[4:6]; currentLine == '00'"                                                                       
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.102 usec per loop
```

So, you could do this:

```
with open(txtFile, 'r') as txt: 
for line in txt:
    currentLine = line[4:6]
    if currentLine == '00':
        #do some actions here
    elif currentLine == '01':
        #do some actions here
    #...
    #and so on
    # and of course write to SQL file
```

Comment: great answer! thanks, Im sure that with all of this I can get some improvement. I mark this as an answer of course!!